# google cloud sql permission

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

i'm following some example in google clould sql tutorial.

- https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java#register_the_driver

it's program using google app engine with google clould sql

whenever i tried to access web console window error - java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc)

but oddly when i runs server as my computer, it works but when deploying, it does not.
by the way there is always same error message whether or not it wokrs

plz help me out

Comment: hi. I tried this one just now and it works fine for me. I want to know more on what you want to do actually, what you have done to trouble shoot your problem

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the local driver isn't registered for local appserver to use.

See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java#using_the_java_development_server

Make sure the following command line arguments are specified.

--jvm_flag=-Drdbms.server=local \
--jvm_flag=-Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--jvm_flag=-Drdbms.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase?user=username&password=password